# Page updates not reflect on staging tasks list in Kentico

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico, staging

Any ideas why small changes on a page like a field value or attachment did not appear on staging tasks list?

- Pages on dev and live have same GUID and alias.
- No workflow enabled on the site.
- Staging works well for new page, partly for old pages, object changes, etc

Additionally: I created stage instance from dev then adjusted dev as source and stage as the target server. Staging works for new products and for some old products.

Staging settings on dev site
[Staging settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKl80.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why changes wouldn't be logged as synchronization tasks (moreover when creating new pages get logged). Did you confirm those changes by clicking the Save button. Also some changes are not content/page related and could be logged as page template object changes -> like changes on the Design tab (web part properties, layouts, web part zones, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes after click Save. btw: I use MVC approach.

Comment: Don't you have any event handler that would prevent staging task to be logged?